# Invoking void function with two arguments in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, cordova, cordova-plugins, xcode9

I'm writing a custom Cordova plugin to invoke the [Guided Access](https://support.apple.com/en-us/ht202612) mode of iOS using [UIAccessibilityRequestGuidedAccessSession](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/1615186-uiaccessibilityrequestguidedacce?language=objc) and I wrote the following code in `cordova-ios-guided-access.m`:

```
#import <Cordova/CDV.h>

@interface WPGuidedAccessMode : CDVPlugin {
  // Member variables go here.
}

- (void)start:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command;
@end

@implementation WPGuidedAccessMode

- (void)start:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command {
    BOOL enableFoo = true;

    UIAccessibilityRequestGuidedAccessSession(enableFoo completion:^(BOOL didSucceed) {
        NSLog(@"Animation over..");
        NSLog(didSucceed ? @"Yes" : @"No");
    });
}

@end
```

But when I'm running this code, I'm getting the following error:

[image]

I tried other few syntaxes as well and went through various SO links for invoking the functions but nothing worked. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `,` after `enableFoo` and need to remove `completion:`

It should be

```
UIAccessibilityRequestGuidedAccessSession(enableFoo, ^(BOOL didSucceed) {
    NSLog(@"Animation over..");
    NSLog(didSucceed ? @"Yes" : @"No");
});
```

Comment: You gotta be kidding me :8

Comment: Worked in one go!! Thanks a ton! I'm starting learning Objective-C as well

Comment: Welcome :). If you are starting learning Objective-C, don't write full method. Just write some first character, after that use XCode suggestion and press Enter. XCode will write method with right syntax for you :D

Comment: Thanks for the XCode suggestion tip